# Writing a turtle program that asks for input and turns 5 times and forward 100 each time

Tags: python

I've seen some similar questions, but they seemed to use some other programming language

So far I've got:

```
import turtle
turns=turtle.Turtle()

degree=input('enter a number: ')

for i in range(5):
    turtle.left(degree)
    turtle.forward(100);
```

Running this doesn't ask me to input a number and thus doesn't print anything

Comment: Try moving the `input` line before the `turtle.Turle()` line. Although this code works for me in python2

Comment: What environment are you running turtle under?  Is this command line Python, IDLE, online web programming site, etc.?  Be specific and you should get specific help.  Your question and subsequent responses to comments seems to indicate that this is not generic Python turtle.

Comment: I'm supposed to use Idle3, but I was told Wingware is alright to use so I'm using that. Thanks for helping guys, turns out I had to place the input line before turtle.Turtle() like jgritty said.

Answer (score 1):

You should give commands to your turtle, which you named `turns`.
You invoked the methods on the class as a whole, which doesn't do anything useful for you.  Try this:

```
for i in range(5):
    turns.left(degree)
    turns.forward(100)
```

For the input, just follow any input example for your Python version.  For instance, for Python 3, try

```
degree = int(input("Enter the angle of the turn in degrees:"))
```

Also try inserting some debugging `print` statements to track the data and control flow.

Comment: Wow didn't notice that. Fixed it, but it still doesn't let me enter an input number and just goes straight to the turtle graphics

Comment: Your "invoked the methods on the class as a whole" explanation is incorrect.  The turtle portion of the OP's code should have worked, but on the *default* turtle instead of the intentionally created turtle in `turns`.  The `input()` portion of the OP's code clearly needed work.